# Are these Memory Leaks Real

Tags: delphi

I have been running FastMM4 on my code to see if I have any memory leaks...

This has reported a load of class UniCodeString leaks when I close the program.  Are these real and how do I interpret the Event Log:  This is a typical block report:

```
--------------------------------2020/10/21 17:32:01--------------------------------
A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 120

This block was allocated by thread 0x5648, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
430547 [FastMM4.pas][FastMM4][_ZN7Fastmm411DebugGetMemEx][8737]
409534 [System.pas][System][_ZN6System7_GetMemEx][4803]
412F8C [System.pas][System][_ZN6System17_NewUnicodeStringEi][25403]
414C3C [System.pas][System][_ZN6System16InternalUStrCatNERNS_13UnicodeStringEiPS0_][29902]
4156CB [System.pas][System][_ZN6System9_UStrCatNERNS_13UnicodeStringEi][30998]
5DD71A [System.IniFiles.pas][System.IniFiles][_ZN6System8Inifiles11TMemIniFile8TSection9SetValuesEiNS_13UnicodeStringE][852]
5DEFA6 [System.IniFiles.pas][System.IniFiles][_ZN6System8Inifiles11TMemIniFile11WriteStringENS_13UnicodeStringES2_S2_][1212]
14F335F [IDEIni.pas][IDEIni][_ZN6Ideini15TIDEIniSettings13UpdateSectionEN6System13UnicodeStringE][1153]
14F26E7 [IDEIni.pas][IDEIni][_ZN6Ideini15TIDEIniSettings13UpdateSectionEi][1087]
14F24FD [IDEIni.pas][IDEIni][_ZN6Ideini15TIDEIniSettings4SaveEiiiiibjPN6System7Classes8TStringsENS1_13UnicodeStringE][1078]
14DE604 [IDEMain.pas][IDEMain][_ZN7Idemain10TfmIDEMain9FormCloseEPN6System7TObjectERNS1_7Uitypes12TCloseActionE][573]

The block is currently used for an object of class: UnicodeString

The allocation number is: 675683

Current memory dump of 256 bytes starting at pointer address 7FF4FBF7E170:
24 D9 69 01 B0 04 02 00 01 00 00 00 29 00 00 00 50 00 61 00 74 00 68 00 3D 00 43 00 3A 00 5C 00
50 00 72 00 6F 00 67 00 72 00 61 00 6D 00 20 00 46 00 69 00 6C 00 65 00 73 00 20 00 28 00 78 00
38 00 36 00 29 00 5C 00 50 00 72 00 6F 00 74 00 6F 00 6E 00 49 00 44 00 45 00 5C 00 50 00 44 00
53 00 00 00 CA 9A 8A F5 AF D5 F2 FF 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 81 E3 F7 FB F4 7F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 37 48 0A 00 47 05 43 00 00 00 00 00 B6 08 43 00 00 00 00 00
9D 95 40 00 00 00 00 00 1C 54 41 00 00 00 00 00 11 55 41 00 00 00 00 00 01 56 45 01 00 00 00 00
63 02 46 01 00 00 00 00 E2 1E 46 01 00 00 00 00 92 9B 68 00 00 00 00 00 A5 04 41 00 00 00 00 00
$  Ù  i  .  °  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  )  .  .  .  P  .  a  .  t  .  h  .  =  .  C  .  :  .  \  .
P  .  r  .  o  .  g  .  r  .  a  .  m  .     .  F  .  i  .  l  .  e  .  s  .     .  (  .  x  .
8  .  6  .  )  .  \  .  P  .  r  .  o  .  t  .  o  .  n  .  I  .  D  .  E  .  \  .  P  .  D  .
S  .  .  .  Ê  š  Š  õ  ¯  Õ  ò  ÿ  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .    ã  ÷  û  ô    .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  7  H  .  .  G  .  C  .  .  .  .  .  ¶  .  C  .  .  .  .  .
  •  @  .  .  .  .  .  .  T  A  .  .  .  .  .  .  U  A  .  .  .  .  .  .  V  E  .  .  .  .  .
c  .  F  .  .  .  .  .  â  .  F  .  .  .  .  .  ’  ›  h  .  .  .  .  .  ¥  .  A  .  .  .  .  .
```

Most of the leaks are small, less than 200 bytes but should I be worrying about them?

Comment: Yes they look real. Yes you should be worrying about them.

Comment: I agree with @DavidHeffernan, but want to clarify one thing: Of course, if you leak 1 kB per day and your application typically isn't run for many years, that amount of wasted memory isn't even going to be noticed by any user. However, well-programmed software doesn't leak, so if you have a leak, then that's an indication that you don't have a complete understanding of how the program works, and so one can suspect that there are worse problems. Having no detected memory leaks is a necessary condition for a software to be of high quality, but not a sufficient condition, though.

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using? Your leak reports says that leak is a concatenated string inside of `TSection.SetValues()` inside of `TMemIniFile.WriteString()`. It is unlikely that `TMemIniFile` would leak that. I have RTL source code only up to XE3, and there is no `TSection` present in `System.IniFiles.pas` in that version, so that must be a more recent addition to `TMemIniFile`'s implementation, so it is *possible but unlikely* that `TMemIniFile` has a leak bug in it. Are you sure you are not leaking the `TMemIniFile` itself? What other leaks are being reported?

Comment: Section is a variable used to define the section name under which a key value will be stored.  UpdateSection is the name of the routine I call to update the section.

Comment: Dude, make a [mcve], or extend the leak report stack trace so you can trace the allocation that leaks. Speculation pointless.

Comment: @JohnBarrat The report shows `TIDEIniSettings.UpdateSection()` calling `TMemIniFile.WriteString()` and the actual leak is inside of `TMemIniFile` itself, specifically in `TMemIniFile.TSection.SetValues()`. I'm guessing (since I don't have your version of Delphi to look at) that `TMemIniFile` is concatenating strings together and then storing the result in a `TSection` object that is not being freed properly. That is why I asked about other leaks in the report that you haven't shown, and the possibility of you maybe leaking the `TMemIniFile` object itself.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the leak report shown already includes a stack trace of the allocation that leaked

Comment: @remy it's not clear if it goes far enough up the stack to identify it uniquely

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the stack trace starts at a `TForm.OnClose` event handler, `Idemain.TfmIDEMain.FormClose()`, goes through a few of the OP's own methods, into `TMemIniFile`, and ending with `Fastmm4.DebugGetMem()` in `System._GetMem()`. Seems pretty complete to me, at least for the 1 leak shown. But the OP does indicate there are "a load of class UniCodeString leaks" which have not been shown yet.

Comment: @JohnBarrat how many `UnicodeString` leaks are you actually seeing? Are they all related to `TMemIniFile`?  Or do they appear to originate from somewhere else?  Can you show more of the leak report?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Are these real

Very likely.  Particularly the one you have shown, yes.

> how do I interpret the Event Log

The leak report you have shown indicates a `UnicodeString` is leaked.  `UnicodeString` is a managed type.  The only times I have ever seen a `UnicodeString` being leaked are when:

- it is a member of a `class` or `record`, and a dynamically allocated instance of that type is itself leaked.  A leak report should show this instance being leaked as well.
- a pointer to an allocated `UnicodeString` has been corrupted due to being overwritten unexpectedly, usually by a logic bug somewhere in the code.
- it is declared as a `threadvar` and is not cleared manually before a thread exits. This is [documented behavior](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variables_(Delphi)#Thread-local_Variables):

  > Dynamic variables that are ordinarily managed by the compiler (long strings, wide strings, dynamic arrays, variants, and interfaces) can be declared with `threadvar`, but the compiler does not automatically free the heap-allocated memory created by each thread of execution. If you use these data types in thread variables, it is your responsibility to dispose of their memory from within the thread, before the thread terminates.

Let's look at your shown report more closely.

```
    A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 120
```

Self-explanatory.  A memory block allocated with a size of 120 bytes was leaked.

```
    This block was allocated by thread 0x5648, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
    430547 [FastMM4.pas][FastMM4][_ZN7Fastmm411DebugGetMemEx][8737]
    409534 [System.pas][System][_ZN6System7_GetMemEx][4803]
    412F8C [System.pas][System][_ZN6System17_NewUnicodeStringEi][25403]
    414C3C [System.pas][System][_ZN6System16InternalUStrCatNERNS_13UnicodeStringEiPS0_][29902]
    4156CB [System.pas][System][_ZN6System9_UStrCatNERNS_13UnicodeStringEi][30998]
    5DD71A [System.IniFiles.pas][System.IniFiles][_ZN6System8Inifiles11TMemIniFile8TSection9SetValuesEiNS_13UnicodeStringE][852]
    5DEFA6 [System.IniFiles.pas][System.IniFiles][_ZN6System8Inifiles11TMemIniFile11WriteStringENS_13UnicodeStringES2_S2_][1212]
    14F335F [IDEIni.pas][IDEIni][_ZN6Ideini15TIDEIniSettings13UpdateSectionEN6System13UnicodeStringE][1153]
    14F26E7 [IDEIni.pas][IDEIni][_ZN6Ideini15TIDEIniSettings13UpdateSectionEi][1087]
    14F24FD [IDEIni.pas][IDEIni][_ZN6Ideini15TIDEIniSettings4SaveEiiiiibjPN6System7Classes8TStringsENS1_13UnicodeStringE][1078]
    14DE604 [IDEMain.pas][IDEMain][_ZN7Idemain10TfmIDEMain9FormCloseEPN6System7TObjectERNS1_7Uitypes12TCloseActionE][573]
```

The leaked memory was allocated by a thread whose ID was `0x5648` at runtime.  The stack trace shows the chain of function calls that led up to the allocation of the memory block that was leaked.  In this case, the stack trace begins at your `TForm.OnClose` event handler, so that thread was clearly the main UI thread.  The actual chain of function calls was then:

- `IDEMain.TfmIDEMain.FormClose()` in `IDEMain.pas`, which called:
- `IDEIni.TIDEIniSettings.Save()` in `IDEIni.pas`, which called:
- `IDEIni.TIDEIniSettings.UpdateSection(Integer)` in `IDEIni.pas`, which called:
- `IDEIni.TIDEIniSettings.UpdateSection(UnicodeString)` in `IDEIni.pas`, which called:
- `System.IniFiles.TMemIniFile.WriteString()` in `System.IniFiles.pas`, which called:
- `System.IniFiles.TMemIniFile.TSection.SetValues()` in `System.IniFiles.pas`, which called:
- `System._UStrCatN()` in `System.pas`, which called:
- `System.InternalUStrCatN()` in `System.pas`, which called:
- `System._NewUnicodeString()` in `System.pas`, which called:
- `System._GetMem()` in `System.pas`, which called:
- `FastMM4.DebugGetMem()` in `FastMM4.pas`, which allocated the memory that was leaked

So, your `OnClose` handler was saving a string value to an `.INI` file, and internally that write performed a string concatenation inside of `TSection.SetValues()`, the result of which was leaked.  I'm guessing because the concatenated string was saved in a `TSection` object that was itself leaked.

```
    The block is currently used for an object of class: UnicodeString
```

Self-explanatory.

```
    The allocation number is: 675683
```

FastMM keeps track of how many memory allocations it performs during the lifetime of the program.

```
    Current memory dump of 256 bytes starting at pointer address 7FF4FBF7E170:
    24 D9 69 01 B0 04 02 00 01 00 00 00 29 00 00 00 50 00 61 00 74 00 68 00 3D 00 43 00 3A 00 5C 00
    50 00 72 00 6F 00 67 00 72 00 61 00 6D 00 20 00 46 00 69 00 6C 00 65 00 73 00 20 00 28 00 78 00
    38 00 36 00 29 00 5C 00 50 00 72 00 6F 00 74 00 6F 00 6E 00 49 00 44 00 45 00 5C 00 50 00 44 00
    53 00 00 00 CA 9A 8A F5 AF D5 F2 FF 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 81 E3 F7 FB F4 7F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 37 48 0A 00 47 05 43 00 00 00 00 00 B6 08 43 00 00 00 00 00
    9D 95 40 00 00 00 00 00 1C 54 41 00 00 00 00 00 11 55 41 00 00 00 00 00 01 56 45 01 00 00 00 00
    63 02 46 01 00 00 00 00 E2 1E 46 01 00 00 00 00 92 9B 68 00 00 00 00 00 A5 04 41 00 00 00 00 00
    $  Ù  i  .  °  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  )  .  .  .  P  .  a  .  t  .  h  .  =  .  C  .  :  .  \  .
    P  .  r  .  o  .  g  .  r  .  a  .  m  .     .  F  .  i  .  l  .  e  .  s  .     .  (  .  x  .
    8  .  6  .  )  .  \  .  P  .  r  .  o  .  t  .  o  .  n  .  I  .  D  .  E  .  \  .  P  .  D  .
    S  .  .  .  Ê  š  Š  õ  ¯  Õ  ò  ÿ  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €
    .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .    ã  ÷  û  ô    .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
    .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  7  H  .  .  G  .  C  .  .  .  .  .  ¶  .  C  .  .  .  .  .
      •  @  .  .  .  .  .  .  T  A  .  .  .  .  .  .  U  A  .  .  .  .  .  .  V  E  .  .  .  .  .
    c  .  F  .  .  .  .  .  â  .  F  .  .  .  .  .  ’  ›  h  .  .  .  .  .  ¥  .  A  .  .  .  .  .
```

This is a dump of the raw data in the memory block that was leaked.  That block was located at memory address `$7FF4FBF7E170`.  The first half is the hex-formatted representation of the raw bytes, and the second half is the human-readable ASCII interpretation of those bytes.

Since we know the block belongs to a `UnicodeString`, we can dig into the data a little further.

A `UnicodeString` begins with a [`StrRec`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString.StrRec) header:

```pascal
StrRec = packed record
{$IF defined(CPUX64)}
  _Padding: LongInt; // Make 16 byte align for payload..
{$ENDIF}
  codePage: Word;
  elemSize: Word;
  refCnt: Longint;
  length: Longint;
end;
```

The format of the name mangling used in the log tells me you are using one of the Clang-based compilers, so if we assume a 64bit compiler, that would make the `StrRec` be 16 bytes in size, and if we break up the first 16 bytes of the dump, we get the following values:

```
24 D9 69 01  _Padding, ignored
B0 04        codePage = 1200, UTF-16
02 00        elemSize = 2, sizeof(WideChar)
01 00 00 00  refCnt   = 1
29 00 00 00  length   = 41 WideChar elements
```

That is consistent with a valid `UnicodeString`.  So, if we then look at the next `((41+1)*2)=84` bytes in the dump, we see the following:

```
50 00 61 00 74 00 68 00 3D 00 43 00 3A 00 5C 00
50 00 72 00 6F 00 67 00 72 00 61 00 6D 00 20 00
46 00 69 00 6C 00 65 00 73 00 20 00 28 00 78 00
38 00 36 00 29 00 5C 00 50 00 72 00 6F 00 74 00
6F 00 6E 00 49 00 44 00 45 00 5C 00 50 00 44 00
53 00 00 00
```

And from the corresponding ASCII dump:

```
P  .  a  .  t  .  h  .  =  .  C  .  :  .  \  .
P  .  r  .  o  .  g  .  r  .  a  .  m  .     .
F  .  i  .  l  .  e  .  s  .     .  (  .  x  .
8  .  6  .  )  .  \  .  P  .  r  .  o  .  t  .
o  .  n  .  I  .  D  .  E  .  \  .  P  .  D  .
S  .  .  .
```

Which, taking UTF-16 into account, forms the Unicode string value:

`'Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\ProtonIDE\PDS'`

That is the actual string that was leaked.  The concatenation operation in `TSection.SetValues()` was likely to join the substrings `'Path'`, `'='`, and `'C:\Program Files (x86)\ProtonIDE\PDS'` together, assuming `TMemIniFile.WriteString()` had been called like this:

```pascal
var Ini: TMemIniFile;
...
Ini.WriteString('Path', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ProtonIDE\PDS');
```

The rest of the dumped data is just random garbage that happened to be in the same memory block, because FastMM allocates memory in buckets of fixed-sized blocks.  In this case, the leaked `UnicodeString` was allocated in a bucket that was using 120-byte blocks.

If I had to guess, either you leaked the `TMemIniFile` object (which should appear elsewhere in the leak report), or `TMemIniFile` in your version of Delphi has a logic bug that leaks a `TSection` object (which should appear elsewhere in the leak report).  This is where you can now start debugging into your code to trace the root cause of the leak.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for that explanation.  I am sure many others will also find this really helpful.

Comment: Another way a UnicodeString could easily leak is if it's declared as a threadvar.